# What is the App URL that SoundCloud is looking for on the API form?

Tags: ios, api, soundcloud, developer-tools, audio-player

I am trying to get access to the SoundCloud API. It is a 2 to 3 week process and I have been rejected now a few times and it is delaying my app development and my launch date. The response I keep getting is generic and unclear as to why I was rejected.

"Hi there,

Thank you for registering your SoundCloud Application. At this time, we cannot grant you access to our SoundCloud Developer Program. Your application has been rejected due to one of the following reasons:

You did not provide sufficient detail within the form for us to review your application.
You provided an email address or SoundCloud profile which is not valid.
Your app does not comply with our API Terms of Use.

We hope you understand that we must be diligent and ensure that no application using our API is in breach of our API Terms of Use, or otherwise breaching creator's rights.

Best,
SoundCloud Team"

The only thing I can think is that the URL they are looking for is wrong. Hence my question:

When the form asks for the App Url. What URL's are accepted?
[image]
I have put in our apps website, our apps Local host 8888, our apps url identifier?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I kinda stuck at the same place and some info wouldn't hurt.

Comment: No I'm afraid not. I got another rejection email and replied saying that I would begin to use and promote mixcloud if they would not help me and low and behold I actually got a response this time. Apparently the reasoning for my rejection was due to an issue with commercialisation in their Ts & Cs. I left the app url blank that time to see if this would work, so if you don't know what to put in here leave it blank because I was talking to someone else online and they left this question blank and were successful. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But there's also another field right at the next page called `Redirect URI for production`, do you have any idea what that is? I kinda figured that it's a callback that's called after authentification process is over, but how do I implement it in Android/IOS?

Comment: I put in "http://appname.com/callback" I think that's what it is after doing some research online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving it blank has worked for some people online.

Comment: Leaving blank is working on live mode ?
Because as per doc you can leave for development mode only.